# my code is working on codepen but not in my browser. i wanted to getelementbyid and then then that element on console

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend, w3c

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Assignment 4</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Biryani</h1>
        <h2 id="hello">Rohan</h2>
        <p>Biryani is Pakistan's special dish. Main Ingredients are rice and chicken.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js
<-- this script is used to getelementbyid "hello" and then displaying on console.-->

```
var myname = document.getElementById("hello");
console.log(myname.innerHTML);
const el = document.querySelector('h2');
el.textContent = 'Assignment 4';
```

Comment: You are displaying this example in codpen from your browser and it works.
In what conditions does it not work? ("in your browser" is confusing, as codpen is already in your browser)
Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. You just need to move your script tag just before you close the body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Assignment 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Biryani</h1>
    <h2 id="hello">Rohan</h2>
    <p>
      Biryani is Pakistan's special dish. Main Ingredients are rice and chicken.
    </p>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include js below of your element definitions.
Browser is compiling html scripts from top to below. If you included js code before all elements defined then that catch nothing and it returns error.

```
...
// your elements are defined here.
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```